# How to delete/remove a selected element in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array-splice

Need you with regards to deleting the element in an array (lets concentrate in the selectedCategory[]), When i tick the checkbox the return wil be the below

["A", "B", "C", "D"]

My problem now is when I untick my selected category (for example, B), the return will be empty.

My expected result would be like:

["A", "C", "D"]

And depends on what category i perform the unticking and will not delete all from category.. e.g:

["A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D"]

should delete single "B" only

```
state = {
    selectedColor: [],
    selectedCategory: [],
}

  onlclickedSelectColor = (event, category) => { 
    const {selectedColor} = this.state;
    let color = event.target.value !== this.state.selectedColor
                      ? event.target.value : '';


        //UNTICK
      if (selectedColor.find((data)=> data === color)) {
          let filteredArray = selectedColor.filter(item => item !== color)
          this.setState({
              selectedColor: filteredArray,
              selectedCategory : selectedCategory .slice(category, 1) //this is the problem, category could be "A"..ect..
          });
        } 
        //TICKING
        else {
          this.setState({
            selectedColor : selectedColor.concat(color),
            selectedCategory : selCategory.concat(category)
          }, () => { this.checkMandatoryFields(); });            
        }

  }


render () {

return (
                           // this map is from backend
                            {colors.map((clr, index) => (
                              <TableRow hover tabIndex={-1}>
                                <TableCell key={`cell-${index}`} style={{ paddingRight: 0, paddingLeft: 0  }}>
                                                                   
                                    <Checkbox
                                      checked={selectedColor.includes(color[`colorID`])}
                                      onChange={(e) => {this.onlclickedSelectColor(e, category)}}
                                      

                                    />
                                  
                                </TableCell>

                              </TableRow>
                              ), this)}

)

}
```

Comment: 1. What is `selCategory`?

Comment: 2. What should be keeped in `selectedCategory`? Array of categories?

Comment: should be ["A", "B", "B","C", "D", "D", "D"], when unticked should be like ["A",  "B","C", "D", "D", "D"], selected untick is "B"

Comment: Could you create a reproducable snippet on this?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no variable initialized, called "category".
2. You get only one parameter from the "onlclickedSelectColor" function.

   // add category parameter

   onlclickedSelectColor = (event, category) => {
   ...
   }

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be several things here.

1. Checkbox is missing a `value` prop.
2. string value on checkbox is compared to an array in state (since your accessing the dom value property (e.target.value). so `color` will always be `' '` and so untick will never enter a true state that actually executes the code.
3. There is no variable definition for `category` so the in1ClickedSelectColor is always sent with `(e, undefined)`.

Hope this helps you on your way.

If you struggle further, it would be most helpful if you create a snippet that reproduces your issue.

[image: Location of snippet generator]